# Using widget from library error The element type '{widget}' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, widget

I'm new to flutter but I couldn't find an answer to this.

I'm playing around with it, trying various libraries. What I noticed, most of them doest build anymore. I'm not sure why. Let's say I want to use this library https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg

I simply copy paste their code

```
final String assetName = 'assets/image_that_does_not_exist.svg';
final Widget svg = new SvgPicture.asset(
  assetName,
);
```

And in my build method I return `svg`.

I receive an error:

```
The element type 'SvgPicture' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'
```

Why is so? It's not only this, but many more libraries are not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Code:

```
final String assetName = 'assets/image_that_does_not_exist.svg';
final svg = new SvgPicture.asset(
  assetName,
);
```

Use it directly as a Widget in your widget tree and it will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Unfortunately your solutions gives this error ```The return type 'SvgPicture' isn't a 'Widget', as defined by the method 'build'.```

Comment: What is the current version of your package?

Comment: Package is Latest - 0.14.0

Comment: Add dot operator(.) to SvgPicture.asset(assetName) and see what suggestions you get, just in case.

Comment: Mohit, it's not about docs. I've tried like 10 libraries, 8 of those doesn't work with similar issues. Wrong return/element type. That's why I'm suspecting that there were some changes made with Flutter that broke those libs. This one for example https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper . I receive error ```The return type 'Swiper' isn't a 'Widget', as defined by the method 'build'.``` even though it's widget

Comment: Add dot operator(.) to SvgPicture.asset(assetName) and see what suggestions you get, just in case

Comment: Didnt work. What worked is adding ```as Widget```.. Mystery.

Comment: So did you get the desired output?

Comment: Didn't check in the end, just was happy it works. Web is very not stable therefore cannot verify exactly, what's the issue :) Thanks for help!

Comment: In the end it didn't work. I found it s a problem with dependencies. ```Because flutter_svg 0.14.0 requires the Flutter SDK and no versions of flutter_svg match >0.14.0 <0.15.0, flutter_svg ^0.14.0 is forbidden.
So, because test_web depends on flutter_svg ^0.14.0, version solving failed.```